# base url with virtual hosts with play framework

Tags: apache, playframework, playframework-2.0

is there a way to "trick" the Play Framwork into thinking it is in root directory even though it is not

I've design my app to be at the root of the server but in reality, it needs to be in a directory "lrs" so thebaseurl/lrs

so 
ProxyPass /lrs -> 127.0.0.1:9000
ProxyPassReverse /lrs -> 127.0.0.1:900

I've set up a proxy but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

application.context="/lrs" inside my application.conf